# Change a file's content to match specific CRC32

Tags: crc, brute-force

I need help, or direction in how to change a file's content(while still including something in it) in a way that can make its CRC specific. It has some restrictions: I need to include some lines of code, and the PNG declaration at the beginning of the file, yes, it's for LFI.
It's not for malicious hacking purposes.

Comment: Brute force it. CRC32 has 32 bits, in your case you know those 32 bits. Randomly or sequentially add all numbers from `0x00000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF` to your file. Check if CRC is correct, repeat if not.

Answer (score 2):

[My spoof code](https://github.com/madler/spoof) takes a set of bit locations in a message, the current CRC, and the desired CRC, and it will tell you which of those locations to invert to get the desired CRC. It simply solves a set of linear equations to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you help me run it? I'm having trouble mostly because I'm not familiar with C or how to run it or insert the parameters. Thanks ahead.

Comment: The comments in spoof.c show an example of use. I don't think I can be any more clear than that.

Comment: The mergesort method seems to be missing, or should be included?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Trying to run it on an online compiler, since visual studio throws a lot of compilation errors.

Comment: You can change `mergesort` to `qsort`.